# SpringMVC project not started with out errors and strack trace

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-java-config

Some body can tell me, where or what I do wrong?
Here is all project: [GitHub](https://github.com/intrade/web)

In project is used Spring 3.2.0.RELEASE
And Java configuration, with out XML config.

IDE run Tomcat and then write: artifact not deployed. See previous errors. But I've can't see errors.

Here is output of IntelliJ IDEA:

```
2014.5.2 09:56:26 org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init
INFO: Loaded APR based Apache Tomcat Native library 1.1.27 using APR version 1.4.6.
2014.5.2 09:56:26 org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init
INFO: APR capabilities: IPv6 [true], sendfile [true], accept filters [false], random [true].
2014.5.2 09:56:26 org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener initializeSSL
INFO: OpenSSL successfully initialized (OpenSSL 1.0.1d 5 Feb 2013)
2014.5.2 09:56:27 org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-apr-8080"]
2014.5.2 09:56:27 org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-apr-8009"]
2014.5.2 09:56:27 org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 1394 ms
2014.5.2 09:56:27 org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service Catalina
2014.5.2 09:56:27 org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.37
2014.5.2 09:56:27 org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-apr-8080"]
2014.5.2 09:56:27 org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-apr-8009"]
2014.5.2 09:56:27 org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 84 ms
Connected to server
[2014-02-05 09:56:27,627] Artifact web:war exploded: Artifact is being deployed, please wait...
2014.5.2 09:56:27 org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader validateJarFile
INFO: validateJarFile(C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\web\target\web\WEB-INF\lib\servlet-api-2.5.jar) - jar not loaded. See Servlet Spec 2.3, section 9.7.2. Offending class: javax/servlet/Servlet.class
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
2014.5.2 09:56:29 org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: Error listenerStart
2014.5.2 09:56:29 org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: Context [] startup failed due to previous errors
[2014-02-05 09:56:29,785] Artifact web:war exploded: Error during artifact deployment. See server log for details.
2014.5.2 09:56:37 org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory D:\apache-tomcat-7.0.37\webapps\manager
```

Tomcat Catalina log:

```
2014.5.2 09:56:26 org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init
SEVERE: Error listenerStart
2014.5.2 09:56:29 org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: Context [] startup failed due to previous errors
2014.5.2 09:56:37 org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
```

Here is configuration classes:
Initializer.java:

```
import org.springframework.core.annotation.Order;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.support.AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer;

@Order(1)
public class Initializer extends
        AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
        return new Class[] { RootConfig.class };
    }
    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
        return new Class[] { WebAppConfig.class };
    }
    @Override
    protected String[] getServletMappings() {
        return new String[] { "/" };
    }
}
```

RootConfig.java:

```
package lv.intrade.web.init;

import java.util.Properties;

import javax.annotation.Resource;
import javax.sql.DataSource;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.PropertySource;
import org.springframework.core.env.Environment;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaRepositories;
import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource;
import org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.EnableTransactionManagement;

@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@ComponentScan("lv.intrade.web")
@PropertySource("classpath:application.properties")
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = {"lv.intrade.web"})
public class RootConfig {

    private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_DATABASE_DRIVER = "db.driver";
    private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_DATABASE_PASSWORD = "db.password";
    private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_DATABASE_URL = "db.url";
    private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_DATABASE_USERNAME = "db.username";

    private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_DIALECT = "hibernate.dialect";
    private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_SHOW_SQL = "hibernate.show_sql";
    private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_ENTITYMANAGER_PACKAGES_TO_SCAN = "entitymanager.packages.to.scan";

    @Resource
    private Environment env;

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();

        dataSource.setDriverClassName(env.getRequiredProperty(PROPERTY_NAME_DATABASE_DRIVER));
        dataSource.setUrl(env.getRequiredProperty(PROPERTY_NAME_DATABASE_URL));
        dataSource.setUsername(env.getRequiredProperty(PROPERTY_NAME_DATABASE_USERNAME));
        dataSource.setPassword(env.getRequiredProperty(PROPERTY_NAME_DATABASE_PASSWORD));

        return dataSource;
    }
//
    @Bean
    public LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory() {
        LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactoryBean = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
        sessionFactoryBean.setDataSource(dataSource());
        sessionFactoryBean.setPackagesToScan(env.getRequiredProperty(PROPERTY_NAME_ENTITYMANAGER_PACKAGES_TO_SCAN));
        sessionFactoryBean.setHibernateProperties(hibProperties());
        return sessionFactoryBean;
    }
//
    private Properties hibProperties() {
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.put(PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_DIALECT, env.getRequiredProperty(PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_DIALECT));
        properties.put(PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_SHOW_SQL, env.getRequiredProperty(PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_SHOW_SQL));
        return properties;
    }
//
    @Bean
    public HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager() {
        HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager = new HibernateTransactionManager();
        transactionManager.setSessionFactory(sessionFactory().getObject());
        return transactionManager;
    }
    @Bean
    public JpaTransactionManager jpaTransactionManager() {
        JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
        transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(entityManagerFactory().getObject());
        return transactionManager;
    }
    @Bean
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory() {
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactoryBean = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();

        entityManagerFactoryBean.setDataSource(dataSource());
        entityManagerFactoryBean.setJpaVendorAdapter(new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter());
        entityManagerFactoryBean.setPackagesToScan(new String[]{"lv.intrade.web"});

        Properties jpaProperties = new Properties();
        jpaProperties.put("hibernate.dialect", env.getRequiredProperty("hibernate.dialect"));
        jpaProperties.put("hibernate.format_sql", true);
        jpaProperties.put("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", env.getRequiredProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto"));
        jpaProperties.put("hibernate.show_sql", env.getRequiredProperty("hibernate.show_sql"));
        entityManagerFactoryBean.setJpaProperties(jpaProperties);

        return entityManagerFactoryBean;
    }
}
```

WebAppConfig.java:

```
package lv.intrade.web.init;

import lv.intrade.web.service.Dictionary;
import org.springframework.context.MessageSource;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.support.AbstractMessageSource;
import org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.HandlerMapping;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.LocaleResolver;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.InterceptorRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.ResourceHandlerRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.LocaleChangeInterceptor;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.SessionLocaleResolver;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver;

import java.util.Locale;

@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan("lv.intrade")
public class WebAppConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Bean
    public UrlBasedViewResolver setupViewResolver() {
        UrlBasedViewResolver resolver = new UrlBasedViewResolver();
        resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/pages/");
        resolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
        resolver.setViewClass(JstlView.class);
        return resolver;
    }
    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry){
        registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**").addResourceLocations("/resources/");
    }

    @Bean
    public MessageSource configureMessageSource() {
        AbstractMessageSource messageSource = new Dictionary();
        return messageSource;
    }

    @Bean
    public LocaleResolver localeResolver() {
        SessionLocaleResolver lr = new SessionLocaleResolver();
        lr.setDefaultLocale(Locale.ENGLISH);
        return lr;
    }

    @Bean
    public LocaleChangeInterceptor localeChangeInterceptor(){
        LocaleChangeInterceptor localeChangeInterceptor=new LocaleChangeInterceptor();
        localeChangeInterceptor.setParamName("lang");
        return localeChangeInterceptor;
    }

    @Override
    public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {
        registry.addInterceptor(localeChangeInterceptor());
    }

//    @Bean
//    public HandlerMapping handlerMapping() {
//        final LocaleChangeInterceptor interceptor = new LocaleChangeInterceptor();
//        interceptor.setParamName("lang");
//
//        final DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping ret = new DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping();
//        ret.setInterceptors(new Object[] { interceptor });
//        return ret;
//    }
}
```

Comment: I've not included application properties ih repository because his contains some private data. But I think you can create it.

Comment: We are not here to debug your project for you. Provide all relevant information in your question. It seems your problem lies with the IDE and Tomcat integration. Likely something is misconfigured.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found problem!

1. I have wrong path till application.properties file.
2. When I fix first problem, I found problem in my AbstractMessageSource class
3. End last problem, when I still have not comment back my jpaTransactionManager - @EnableJpaRepositories - not working.

Now all work fine!
Thank you for all for help and ideas! Many thanks for Orchid for good idea, but with servlet-api-2.5 all is ok! :)

Answer (score 3):

[Try **this** solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2641338/how-to-resolve-error-listenerstart-when-deploying-web-app-in-tomcat-5-5)

Also check whether you have placed servlet-api-2.5.jar correctly.

Error log is not complete. Add complete log.