# SEVERE: Exception org.springframework.web.util.Log4jConfigListener

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

Getting the below severe exception when attempting to run tomcat in Spring Tool Suite:

```
SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class    org.springframework.web.util.Log4jConfigListener
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot set web app root system property when WAR file is not expanded
at    org.springframework.web.util.WebUtils.setWebAppRootSystemProperty(WebUtils.java:143)
at    org.springframework.web.util.Log4jWebConfigurer.initLogging(Log4jWebConfigurer.java:117)
at    org.springframework.web.util.Log4jConfigListener.contextInitialized(Log4jConfigListener.java:45)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4939)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5434)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

See [this post](https://springframework-user.narkive.com/6NpiYW7o/cannot-set-web-app-root-system-property-when-war-file-is-not-expanded#post3)

> Don't use `Log4jConfigListener` within a WAR that is not **expanded**; we probably
> need to make that even clearer.
>
> There's only two benefits that `Log4jWebConfigurer` gives you:
>
> - refreshes Log4J configuration when the Log4J config file changes;
> - allows to use log file paths relative to the web applicaiton root.
>
> Both are not applicable when the WAR is not expanded, so there's no point in
> using `Log4jWebConfigurer` in such a scenario. Simply rely on Log4J's default
> initialization from a `log4j.properties` file in the root of the classpath.
>
> BTW, you might have noticed that `Log4jConfigListener` is commented-out in
> Petclinic's and Countries' `web.xml`, for a related reason: To be able to deploy
> WARs that are not expanded, and to work without hassle in JBoss (which has its
> own special usage of Log4J).
>
> Juergen

Answer (score 2):

Log4jConfigListener only works if the WAR file is exploded. Read this article: http://community.jaspersoft.com/wiki/illegalstateexception-while-deploying-war-file-weblogic